# Some doubts in the definition of some random variables in stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

There is this passage about Poisson process in the textbook Stochastics by Hans-Otto, Georgii.

Here is a copy of the text:

Let $\alpha>0$ and $(L_i)_i\geq0$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables that are exponentially distributed with parameter $\alpha$; Theorem $(3.26)$ guarantess the existence of such a sequence on a suitable probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. We interpret $L_i$ as the gap between the $(i-1)$st and the $i$th point; then $T_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k}L_i$ is the $k$th random point in time. Let

$$N_t=\sum_{k\geq1}1_{(0,t]}(T_k)$$

be the number of points in the interval $(0,t]$. Thus, for $s<t$, the increment $N_t-N_s$ is the number of points in $(s,t]$.

From my understanding, the unit of $L$ is time, so if we add up all the $L$, we get the total time needed to get the $k$th point. Now if we add up all the $T$, we get $T_1+T_2+T_3+\ldots$ which is the sum of the time to get the first point, the second point and so on. That means $N_t$ has some overlap, since we add $T_1+T_2=L_1+L_1+L_2$, $L_1$ is counted twice. My question is how can $N_t$ be the number of points in the interval $(0,t]$? It should be more than the number of points? Am I wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi what you say is true but doesn't matter. Take a Poisson process trajectory and let's imagine that between $0$ and a fixed time $t>0$, the process has jumped $3$ times at $T_1<T_2<T_3$ of course we have $L_1=T_1,L_2=T_2-T_1,L_3=T_3-T_2$ from your specifications.

Obviously then $N_t=3=\sum_{k>0}1_{(0,t]}(T_k\leq t)=3$ see that here for $k=1,2,3$ we have $1_{(0,t]}(T_k\leq t)=1$ and for $>3,1_{(0,t]}(T_k\leq t)=0$, but notice that you cannot express the value of $N_t$ using a summation with $L_k$ in a simple manner because you have to take into account the past behaviour of $L_i$s, for $i<k$ to determine if you have overshot $t$ or not.

Hope this helps best regards